# How to host a WPF application inside a Win32 application on Windows 10

Tags: wpf, winapi

I need to embedd a window of a WPF application inside a Wind32 application. I use Microsoft Windows [SetParent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setparent) function. On Window 7 it works without any problems, but on Windows 10 the WPF window is invisible. I can see, using Spy++, that it is present on the Win32 form but do not rendered. MoveWindow or SetWindowPos are also do not help to solve the problem. What shell I do to solve this problem?

Comment: The simple answer is: You can't. See [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683). Make sure you understand that *"one [...] of the windows involved is unaware that it is participating in a cross-process window tree"*.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem on win10 2004 using the windows desktop application and wpf app template project in VS. Did you clear the `WS_POPUP` style and set the `WS_CHILD` style before calling SetParent?

Comment: Yes, I remove WS_POPUP style and set WS_CHILD one. The WPF application is developed by foreign Company and it created a lot of invisible windows and only one is visible. I have tried to add all of them as child but also without success. As I wrote the windows is inside the parent window but not rendered.

Comment: As mentioned in Raymond's article above, `SetParent` cross-process is technically legal, but the consequences can be very difficult to manage. Your foreign WPF application seems to be not prepared at all for manipulating its windows in this way.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem using ShowWindow function. The windows repainted only when its minimized and then maximized.